# Reforming the grammar to remove shift reduce conflict in if-then-else

Tags: bison, shift-reduce-conflict

How do I remove shift-reduce conflict for bison for the given grammar?

```
 selection-stmt -> if ( expression ) statement |
                      if ( expression ) statement else statement
```

A solution giving the modified grammar would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For future individuals, [this page](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-7.html) helped me through a similar issue.  Also, pass in switches `--debug` and `--verbose` to bison and look at the generated files.  Not all the information is printed to standard out.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution.  If you know how LR parsers work, then you know that the conflict happens here:

```
if ( expression ) statement * else statement
```

where the star marks the current position of the cursor.  The question the parser must answer is "should I shift, or should I reduce".  Usually, you want to bind the `else` to the closest `if`, which means you want to shift the `else` token now.  Reducing now would mean that you want the `else` to wait to be bound to an "older" `if`.

Now you want to "tell" your parser generator that "when there is a shift/reduce conflict between the token `"else"` and the rule "stm -> if ( exp ) stm", then the token must win".  To do so, "give a name" to the precedence of your rule (e.g., `"then"`), and specify that `"then"` has less precedence than `"else"`.  Something like:

```
// Precedences go increasing, so "then" < "else".
%nonassoc "then"
%nonassoc "else"
%%
stm: "if" "(" exp ")" stm            %prec "then"
   | "if" "(" exp ")" stm "else" stm
```

using Bison syntax.

I'm uneasy with the `%nonassoc` here, because it really says that `"then"` and `"else"` are non associative, which is true in most grammars, but I only meant to give them precedence levels, not associativity.  Bison provides `%precedence` to this end:

```
// Precedences go increasing, so "then" < "else".
%precedence "then"
%precedence "else"
%%
stm: "if" "(" exp ")" stm            %prec "then"
   | "if" "(" exp ")" stm "else" stm
```

Actually, my favorite answer is even to give `"then"` and `"else"` the same precedence.  When the precedences are equal, to break the tie between the token that wants to be shifted, and the rule that wants to be reduced, Bison/Yacc will look at associativity.  Here, you want to promote right-associativity so to speak (more exactly, you want to promote "shift"), so:

```
%right "then" "else" // Same precedence, but "shift" wins.
```

will suffice.

According to [Bison manual (3.8.1)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.pdf), "Neither solution is perfect however."

Comment: How can I do the same if there is a non-terminal N after statement as follows:

IF_KEYWORD '(' expression N ')' M statement N ELSE_KEYWORD M statement

Here, M and N are non-terminal symbols.

Comment: @VishwasJain It all depends on your if-then rule.  If the `"else" M` part is optional, then the same approach should apply.

Comment: Problem Solved!

Answer (score 7):

You need to recognize the fact that the middle `statement` in the if-else case cannot be (or end with) a dangling if (an if with no else.)  The easiest way to do that is to split the `stmt` rule in two:

```
stmt -> stmt-ending-with-dangling-if | stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if
stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if ->
    if ( expression ) stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if else stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if |
    ...other statements not ending with dangling if...
stmt-ending-with-dangling-if ->
    if ( expression ) stmt |
    if ( expression ) stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if else stmt-ending-with-dangling-if |
    ...other statements ending with dangling if...
```

Any other `stmt -> whatever` rule where `whatever` doesn't end with a `stmt` goes in the `stmt-not-ending-with-if` rule, while any `stmt` rule that DOES end in `stmt` get split in two versions; an `not-ending-with-if` version in the `not-ending-with-if` rule and a `dangling-if` version in the `dangling-if` rule.

**edit**

A more complete grammar with other productions:

```
stmt : stmt-ending-with-dangling-if | stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if
stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if :
    IF '(' expr ')' stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if ELSE stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if |
    WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if |
    DO stmt WHILE '(' expr ')' ';' |
    expr ';' |
    '{' stmt-list '}'
stmt-ending-with-dangling-if:
    IF '(' expr ')' stmt |
    IF '(' expr ')' stmt-not-ending-with-dangling-if ELSE stmt-ending-with-dangling-if |
    WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt-ending-with-dangling-if
```

Rules like `WHILE (expr) stmt` get split in two (as they end with `stmt`), while rules like `expr;` do not.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the ...other statements....i have no other productions with selection-stmt, but i am still getting an error saying using useless nonterminals

This is what i did:
selection-stmt : open
  | closed
  ;

open  : IF LFT_BRKT expression RGT_BRKT statement
  | IF LFT_BRKT expression RGT_BRKT closed ELSE open
  ;

closed  : IF LFT_BRKT expression RGT_BRKT closed ELSE closed
  ;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720219/bison-shift-reduce-conflict-unable-to-resolve/12720483#12720483

The complete grammar is here

Comment: you need to rid of all the `xxx-stmt` intermediate non-terminals, combining all the `stmt` rules into a single group, and then split them into dangling/non-dangling if versions.

Comment: what is this stmt that you are using. And also where did the DO come from? Kindly look at the grammar in the link and post the answer. Thanks

Comment: @AakashAnuj: `stmt` here replaces `statement` in you grammar.  Delete all the rules that end in `-stmt` in your grammar, and replace your `statement` rule with the `stmt` rule above.  You can delete the `DO` rule if you don't want it and add `';' | return expression ';' | return ';'`.

Answer (score -2):

make if else higher level than normal statements, like:

```
statements:
  statements lineEnd statement
| statements lineEnd IfStat
| statements lineEnd IfElseStat
| IfStat
| IfElseStat
;
IfStat:
  if ( statement )
;
IfElse:
  IfStat else statement
;
```

Comment: I don't think this could fix the issue.