# yacc Shift/Reduce conflicts

Tags: bison, yacc

For the following grammar i have encountered SR errors.

This is my Grammar

```
program : CLASS Program '{' field_decl '}'
        ;    
field_decl : type field_part ';'
           | field_part field_fact
           | meth_decl
           |
           ;    
field_fact : ',' field_decl
           | field_part
           ;    
field_part  : IDENTIFIER field_part2
            ;    
field_part2 :
            | '[' int_literal ']' field_decl
            ;    
meth_decl   : type meth_decl1
            | VOID meth_decl1
            ;    
meth_decl1  : IDENTIFIER '(' meth_part ')' block 
            ;    
meth_part   : type meth_part1
            |
            ;    
meth_part1  : IDENTIFIER meth_part2
            ;                
meth_part2  :
            | ',' meth_part
            ;    
block       : '{' block_list '}'
            ;    
type        : INT
            | BOOLEAN
            ;    
block_list  : var_decl
            |
            ;    
var_decl    : type ids ';'
            | statement
            ;    
ids         : IDENTIFIER ids_part
            ;    
ids_part    :
            | ',' ids
            ;    
statement   : location ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR expr ';'
            | method_call ';'
            | IF '(' expr ')' block ELSE block 
            | IF '(' expr ')' block
            | FOR IDENTIFIER '=' expr ',' expr block
            | RETURN expr ';'
            | RETURN ';'
            | BREAK ';'
            | CONTINUE ';'
            | block
            ;    
location    : IDENTIFIER loc_part
            ;               
loc_part    : 
            | '[' expr ']'
            ;    
method_call : IDENTIFIER '(' ')'
            | IDENTIFIER '(' expr_block ')'
            | CALLOUT '(' STRING_LITERAL ')'
            | CALLOUT '(' STRING_LITERAL ',' callout_arg_block ')'
            ;    
callout_arg_block : callout_arg
                  | callout_arg ',' callout_arg_block
                  ;    
callout_arg : expr
            | STRING_LITERAL
            ;    
expr        : location
            | method_call
            | literal
            | expr bin_op expr
            | MINUS expr
            | '!' expr
            | '(' expr ')'
            ;    
expr_block  : expr expr_fact
            ;    
expr_fact   : 
            |  ',' expr_block
            ;
bin_op      : ARITHEMATIC_OPERATOR
            | EQUALS_OPERATOR
            | RELATIONAL_OPERATOR
            | CONDITIONAL_OPERATOR
            ;
literal     : int_literal
            | bool_literal
            ;
int_literal : DIGIT
            | HEXADECIMAL_VALUE
            ;
bool_literal    : TRUE
                | FALSE
                ;
```

and the output bison shows is

State 19 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 33 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 87 conflicts: 4 shift/reduce

State 107 conflicts: 4 shift/reduce

how can i rewrite the grammar so as to remove these conflicts

Answer (score 1):

I didn't actually compile the grammar to check, so the following may not be exhaustive.

Basically, you have both of the classic shift/reduce conflicts:

1. Your expression grammar is ambiguous:

   ```
   expr: expr bin_op expr
   ```

   The grammar does not allow the parser to decide which `bin_op` has precedence in any given expression, so it would allow (for example) `3 + 4 * 5` to be parsed as either `expr(3 + 4) bin_op(*) expr(5)` or as `expr(3) bin_op(+) expr(4 * 5)`. The usual solution to this problem is to use precedence declarations, but those are not compatible with clumping all binary operators into a single production.

   See [Yacc/Bison, minimize amount by grouping math ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410875/yacc-bison-minimize-amount-by-grouping-math-ops) and read the [bison manual section on precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Precedence).
2. Your `if` statements are ambiguous. For example, in

   ```
   if ( <expr> ) if ( <expr> ) <block> else <block>
   ```

   the grammar does not specify to which `if` the `else` applies.

   In this specific case, the default bison rule (which is to favour shift over reduce) will do the right thing (by associating the `else` with the innermost `if`), but it will still report a shift/reduce conflict.

   See the bison manual for an example (in the previously-linked section) or look at [Removing shift/reduce conflict on optional else block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550936/removing-shift-reduce-conflict-on-optional-else-block) and [Reforming the grammar to remove shift reduce conflict in if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731922/reforming-the-grammar-to-remove-shift-reduce-conflict-in-if-then-else)