# “IF ELSE” statement inside basic calculator

Tags: jison

I’m trying to implement my own calculator with “IF ELSE” statements.
Here is the basic calculator example:

```
 /* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
"*"                   return '*'
"/"                   return '/'
"-"                   return '-'
"+"                   return '+'
"^"                   return '^'
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
"PI"                  return 'PI'
"E"                   return 'E'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left '^'
%left UMINUS

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF
        {return $1;}
    ;

e
    : e '+' e
        {$$ = $1+$3;}
    | e '-' e
        {$$ = $1-$3;}
    | e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | e '/' e
        {$$ = $1/$3;}
    | e '^' e
        {$$ = Math.pow($1, $3);}
    | '-' e %prec UMINUS
        {$$ = -$2;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | E
        {$$ = Math.E;}
    | PI
        {$$ = Math.PI;}
    ;
```

I don’t understand if I add the “IF” statements like this:

```
IfStatement
: "IF" "(" Expression ")" Statement
    {
        $$ = new IfStatementNode($3, $5, null, createSourceLocation(null, @1, @5));
    }
| "IF" "(" Expression ")" Statement "ELSE" Statement
    {
        $$ = new IfStatementNode($3, $5, $7, createSourceLocation(null, @1, @7));
    }
;
```

The parser generates well.
So how I can use the statement like this IF(5>2)THEN (5+2) ELSE (5*2).
The calculator’s functionality works well of course, but “IF” doesn’t.

Comment: Is your `IfStatement` reachable from the start non-terminal?

Comment: Bryan Olivier, at least, that's how it must be.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for two sorts of constructs: an IF statement and an IF expression.  Fortunately, your example uses the THEN keyword to distinguish them.  Your IF expression production would be something like:

```
IfExpression
: "IF" "(" Expression ")" "THEN" "(" Expression ")"
    {
        $$ = new IfExpressionNode(/* pass arguments as desired */);
    }
| "IF" "(" Expression ")" "THEN" "(" Expression ")" "ELSE" "(" Expression ")"
    {
        $$ = new IfExpressionNode(/* arguments */);
    }
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how your two pieces of grammar are bound together, so it's hard to answer.  Have you also looked at other questions, such as [Reforming the grammar to remove shift reduce conflict in if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731922/reforming-the-grammar-to-remove-shift-reduce-conflict)?