# shift/reduce conflict on symbol ','

Tags: yacc

I have shift-reduce warnings like this:
Can someone explain me what am I missing here?

```
168: shift/reduce conflict (shift 316, reduce 157) on ','
state 168
    static_var_list : static_var_list2 .  (157)
    static_var_list2 : static_var_list2 . ',' T_VARIABLE '=' static_scalar  (158)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reforming the grammar to remove shift reduce conflict in if-then-else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731922/reforming-the-grammar-to-remove-shift-reduce-conflict-in-if-then-else)

Comment: Impossible to give good advice without seeing more of the grammar, but basically the problem is that in the context shown, the `static_var_list` might be followed by a comma from some enclosing production.