# Solving dangling else with bison

Tags: bison

My grammar has these two token declarations:

```
%token RP
%token ELSE
```

And these two rules:

```
Statement  : IF LP Exp RP Statement;

Statement  : IF LP Exp RP Statement ELSE Statement;
```

From what I understand, a rule's priority is determined by the priority of its last nonterminal. Therefore, the first rule has `RP` priority and the second rule has `ELSE` priority which is higher than `RP`. Below is bison's output:

```
state 73

   11 Statement: IF LP Exp RP Statement .
   12          | IF LP Exp RP Statement . ELSE Statement

    ELSE  shift, and go to state 76

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 11 (Statement)]
    $default  reduce using rule 11 (Statement)
```

Shouldn't this conflict be solved by shifting since `ELSE` has higher priority ?

Comment: I flagged the question as a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720219/bison-shift-reduce-conflict-unable-to-resolve)

Comment: @zmo I understand that there's a conflict and I know I can modify the grammar so that the conflict goes away, what I don't understand is why the conflict isn't solved by giving higher priority to the ELSE token

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because `%token` does not set the precedence (what you call the priority) of a token -- it declares the token to exist with NO precedence.  If you want to declare a precedence for the token, you need to use `%left`, `%right` or `%nonassoc` all of which both declare the token AND set its precedence.  If you change your code to

```
%nonassoc RP
%nonassoc ELSE
```

then `RP` and `ELSE` will have have their precedence set, and `ELSE` will have higher precedence, and the shift/reduce conflict will be resolved by precedence.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720219/bison-shift-reduce-conflict-unable-to-resolve), the if/else ambiguity is a pretty common pattern for languages, and it is dealt in Bison's and Yacc's manual, as well as in the dragon books, and on several tutorials on Internet, like [this one](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/if.html)

> Shouldn't this conflict be solved by shifting since ELSE has higher priority ?

as said in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720219/bison-shift-reduce-conflict-unable-to-resolve), it indeed is. The conflict is being solved automatically by bison doing an automatic shift, and it tells you about it.. It indeed selects the IF ELSE, and if you add the `%expect` declaration it won't warn you about that it did something "automatically".

Comment: It's resolved by shifting as that is the default resolution of shift/reduce conflicts.  The OP wants to resolve it by shifting via precedence, which requires setting precedence on the tokens.  The same overall result, but it shuts up the complaint about an unresolved shift/reduce conflict.